# How can I Run XSB on Cygwin?

Tags: path, cygwin, xsb

I tried to run xsb on cygwin64

```
$ xsb
-bash: xsb: command not found
```

the $PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin: /cygdrive/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/C:/IPS/mulval/lib:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB/config/x64-pc-windows/bin/xsb.exe:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB/bin/xsb:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB/config/x64-pc-windows/bin/xsb.dll:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB/config/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/xsb.exe:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB/config/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/xsb.dll:/cygdrive/c/IPS/XSB
```

how can I run xsb on cygwin?
can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

when I put the

```
PATH= C:/IPS/XSB/bin/xsb64
```

it works:

```
$ xsb
[xsb_configuration loaded]
[sysinitrc loaded]
[xsbbrat loaded]

XSB Version 3.6. (Gazpatcho) of April 22, 2015
[i686-pc-cygwin 32 bits; mode: optimal; engine: slg-wam; scheduling: local]
[Build date: 2015-04-30]
```